# Microsoft Daynamics WebApi - The navigation property 'bpf_quoteid' has no expanded value and no 'odata.bind' property annotation

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to link a quote to a bpf instance through Dynamics 365  WebApi :

```
const data = {
            "bpf_quoteid@data.bind": "/" + SelectedEntityTypeName + "s(" + SelectedControlSelectedItemReferences[0].Id.replace('{', '').replace('}', '') + ")"
        }

        Xrm.WebApi.updateRecord(BpfName, Bpf.businessprocessflowinstanceid, data).then(
            function success(result) {
                console.log("Instance of " + BpfName + " updated");
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        );
```

In result I am getting this error (400) :

> An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: The navigation property 'bpf_quoteid' has no expanded value and no 'odata.bind' property annotation. Navigation property in request without expanded value must have the 'odata.bind' property annotation.

Rest of the error message :

> at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadPropertyWithoutValue(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState resourceState, String propertyName)
> at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(PropertyParsingResult propertyParsingResult, String propertyName)
> at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ProcessProperty(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, Func'2 readPropertyAnnotationValue, Action'2 handleProperty)
> at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializer.ReadResourceContent(IODataJsonLightReaderResourceState resourceState)
> at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.StartReadingResource()
> at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadResourceSetItemStart(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, SelectedPropertiesNode selectedProperties)
> at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtStartImplementationSynchronously(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector)
> at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()
> at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)
> at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataReaderExtensions.ReadResourceOrResourceSet(ODataReader reader)
> at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
> at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)

**In my case *the schema name of the lookup field is all lowercase*.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, please ignore me.
The answer is
`bpf_quoteid@odata.bind`
instead of
`bpf_quoteid@data.bind`

(Do you see the missing 'o' ?)

But furthermore, you need to be on the right process stage to fill the quote.
To update the process stage I recommand this blog post : https://carldesouza.com/using-javascript-to-go-to-next-stage-in-business-process-flows/

Comment: Ha! Just saved me!